# How can I make a specific function on action page to handle the form data?

Tags: php, php-7

I have a `models.php` page that contains the specification of form for a specific model.

> models.php

```
$books = [
    ['Book Name', 'text' ],
    ['Author', 'text']
];
$vegetables = [
    ['Name', 'text'],
    ['Photo', 'file']
]
```

Now this page is accessed by an `admin.php` page, which generate an appropriate `HTML form` on the basis of the given `name` and `input type`.

**I want to fill the form and send the data into a `handle.php` and handle the data with the specific function to fill the data into appropriate table.**

> handle.php

```
function books(){
    // this will fill the details into table of books.
    INSERT INTO BOOKS 
        name = $_POST['book_name']
        author $_POST['author']
}

function vegetables(){
    // this will fill the details into table of vegetables.
    INSERT INTO VEGETABLES 
        name = $_POST['book_name']
        photo = $_FILE['photo']
}
```

**(If there's any other better way of doing this, so please mention, I'll do that way and delete my question.)**

Comment: there are many way to do this, your's is one of them. It isn't very flexible though, since you'd have to write a specific function for each model. Now it depends on how scaleable you wanna design that. Optimum would be a base model class that handles all the fetching, inserting, updating, ... based on the (database) configuration in (extending) child-models

Comment: ok, can you give me the link of other ways? And in my case, how can I do it?

Comment: Yeah, firstly I also thought like that, but still not sure exactly how to do it.

Comment: you can have a [look here](https://github.com/jeffstagedoor/Api/blob/master/api/Model.php), that's my version of such a base model class. Just to get an idea of _one of the many_ ways to do that. It's not perfect, nor ready for production. Just for the idea. [This](https://github.com/jeffstagedoor/Api/blob/master/dummy/models/Posts.php) would then be an example of a child model class. Your handle.php would then just determine the right model and use it's methods.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff for the reply. But the codes you sent contains so many members and making me confuse (1500 lines). Can you please minify it  into a snippet which is relevant precisely to my context here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my suggestion. As stated in the comments, this is just *my* way to do such things, it's not necessarily the best solution for every situation.

I have a base model, that defines all methods all model need to have in common. Here's a very simplified version:

```
class Model {

    public $modelName = 'default';
    public $id = null;
    private $fields = [];
    private $tableName = 'default';
    private $tableDefinition = [];
    private $idField = 'id';

    public function insert($dataset) {
       // do some database magic by using $this->fields, or $this->tableDefinition
       $sql = "INSERT into {$this->tableName} ...";
       ...
       return $id;
    }
    public function update($id, $dataset) {
        // do some more database magic by using $this->fields, or $this->tableDefinition
    }

    // many more methods. To get data, delete, sort, ..
    //...
}
```

Every model now extends this base model class and sets it's specific params, maybe even overrides some methods or adds special ones:

```
class Books extends Model {
    public $modelName = 'book';
    private $fields = ['bookName','Author'];
    private $tableName = 'BOOKS';
    private $tableDefinition = [
            ['bookName','varchar'],
            ['Author','varchar']
    ];
    // private $idField = 'id'; // you can ommit that, if it's the default.
}
```

If Vegetables behaves different you can simply override a method:

```
class Vegetables extends Model {
    public $modelName = 'vegetable';
    // set all other properties...

    // override insert() for example
    public function insert($dataset) {
        // do something that doesn't comply with the standard procedure
    }
}
```

Then in handle.php you can do something like this:

```
<?php
$modelName = $request; // get it from your form, your url, ..
                       // & verify this model(file) exists.
$model = new $modelName();
$model->insert($dataSet);
```

Comment: Awesome Explanation @Jeff. You solved lot of my problems in just one answer. BTW I saw you are a musician. Share something, I'd love to see your work. Thanks Again!!

Comment: BTW I have done my 670% work using methods, but after reading this, I'm going to replace my all codes with *your way*.

Comment: I'm pleased that I could help you! Using classes gives so much flexibility and reduces so much code to write.

Answer (score 2):

Make a base interface BaseModel.php
which would have the basic signatures of insertion , updation and selection

Make a derived class  booksModel.php and vegetablesModel.php that would implement the BaseModel class.

In this way, you have made your code extendable. If there is some common functionality, you can make the base class as Abstract class.

```
abstract class BaseModel {
    abstract function add($dataObject);
    abstract function get($dataObject);   
}

class BooksModel extends BaseModel {
    public function add($dataObject) {
        /* Implementation */
    }
    public function get($dataObject) {
        /* Implementation */
    }
}

class VegetableModel extends BaseModel {
    public function add($dataObject) {
        /* Implementation */
    }
    public function get($dataObject) {
        /* Implementation */
    }
}
```